# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'red' of null

Tags: node.js, reactjs, socket.io

```
import React from "react";
import io from "socket.io-client";

class TrafficLight extends React.PureComponent {
  state = { lamp: null, currentcolor: "red" };

  // turnLampOn event handler
  turnLampOn = async () => {
    while (true) {
```

**//Getting the Null error here if I try to run this app in production on Heroku**

```
// currentcolor=red wait 'red' ms and enable 'green'

      await this.waitSomeSeconds("green", this.state.lamp.red);
      // currentcolor=green wait 'green' ms and enable 'yellow'
      await this.waitSomeSeconds("yellow", this.state.lamp.green);
      // currentcolor=yellow wait 'yellow' ms and enable 'red'
      await this.waitSomeSeconds("red", this.state.lamp.yellow);
    }
  };

  waitSomeSeconds = (color, wait) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        console.log(
          this.props.street +
            ": from " +
            this.state.currentcolor +
            " to " +
            color +
            ", wait=" +
            wait
        );
        this.setState({ currentcolor: color });
        resolve();
      }, wait);
    });
  };

  componentDidMount = async () => {
    // connect to server
    //let socket = io.connect("localhost:5000", { forceNew: true });
    // send join message to server, pass a payload to it (street name specified via props)
    // connect to server on Heroku cloud
    const socket = io.connect();

    socket.emit("join", { streetName: this.props.street }, err => {});
    // wait on 'turnLampOn'
    socket.on("turnLampOn", lampData => {
      console.log("turnLampOn", lampData);
      // Set new lamp data and start trafficlight
      if (this.state.lamp === null) {
        this.setState({ lamp: lampData });
```

**//Null value occurs when the app is trying to execute this method.**

```
    this.turnLampOn();
  }
});
```

};

```
  // Get current color helper
  getColor = color => (this.state.currentcolor === color ? color : "white");

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="light">
        <div
          className="lamp"
          style={{ backgroundColor: this.getColor("red"), margin: ".5rem" }}
        />
        <div
          className="lamp"
          style={{ backgroundColor: this.getColor("yellow"), margin: ".5rem" }}
        />
        <div
          className="lamp"
          style={{ backgroundColor: this.getColor("green"), margin: ".5rem" }}
        />
        <div style={{ textAlign: "center", fontName: "Helvetica" }}>
          {this.props.street}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default TrafficLight;
```

**This App works perfectly fine in development mode, the error occurs in production environment.**
**The app has a Node.js server which contains sockect.io to establish connection**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React's [setState](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) function is asynchronous and does not update state immediately. According to documentation

> Think of setState() as a request rather than an immediate command to update the component. For better perceived performance, React may delay it, and then update several components in a single pass. React does not guarantee that the state changes are applied immediately.
>
> setState() does not always immediately update the component. It may batch or defer the update until later. This makes reading this.state right after calling setState() a potential pitfall. Instead, use componentDidUpdate or a setState callback (setState(updater, callback)), either of which are guaranteed to fire after the update has been applied. If you need to set the state based on the previous state, read about the updater argument below.

For further information have a look [here](https://medium.com/@wereHamster/beware-react-setstate-is-asynchronous-ce87ef1a9cf3).

To solve your problem call `turnLampOn` method in callback to `setState`

```
class TrafficLight extends React.PureComponent {
    state = { lamp: null, currentcolor: "red" };

    // turnLampOn event handler
    turnLampOn = async () => {
        while (true) {

            await this.waitSomeSeconds("green", this.state.lamp.red);
            // currentcolor=green wait 'green' ms and enable 'yellow'
            await this.waitSomeSeconds("yellow", this.state.lamp.green);
            // currentcolor=yellow wait 'yellow' ms and enable 'red'
            await this.waitSomeSeconds("red", this.state.lamp.yellow);
        }
    };

    waitSomeSeconds = (color, wait) => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                console.log(
                    this.props.street +
                    ": from " +
                    this.state.currentcolor +
                    " to " +
                    color +
                    ", wait=" +
                    wait
                );
                this.setState({ currentcolor: color });
                resolve();
            }, wait);
        });
    };

    componentDidMount = async () => {
        // connect to server on Heroku cloud
        const socket = io.connect();

        socket.emit("join", { streetName: this.props.street }, err => { });
        // wait on 'turnLampOn'
        socket.on("turnLampOn", lampData => {
            console.log("turnLampOn", lampData);
            // Set new lamp data and start trafficlight
            if (this.state.lamp === null) {
                // To resolve this error you can call `turnLampOn`
                // in a callback passed to setState
                this.setState({ lamp: lampData }, () => this.turnLampOn());
            }
        });
    };
}
```